# How to pass the returned url of my custom map tiles to react-leaflet?

Tags: react-leaflet

// Leaflet:

```
L.TileLayer.Custom = L.TileLayer.extend({
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  getTileUrl({x, y, z}) {
    if (y < 0) {
      y = 0;
    }
    const _x = 'C' + padStart(correctEdges(z, x).toString(16), 8, '0');
    const _y = 'R' + padStart(y.toString(16), 8, '0');
    const _z = 'L' + padStart(z.toString(10), 2, '0');
    return `${url()}${this.options.path}/${_z}/${_y}/${_x}.${this.options.imgType}`;
  }
});
```

I am generating a tile url in leaflet.  How do I pass the returned url of my custom map tiles to react-leaflet TileLayer element?  I will not be using `http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png.`

Instead, the string is dynamically updated

```
${url()}${this.options.path}/${_z}/${_y}/${_x}.${this.options.imgType}

url = <string>
```

// React-Leaflet:

```
<TileLayer
  attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the `url` in state and when

```js
<TileLayer
  ..
  url={this.state.url}
/>
```

Is this what you are asking for?